# Cant make the programm exit after -999 input with summary information

Tags: c++, loops

Task:
Write a program that would (theoretically) remain open, and allow users to enter numbers throughout the day.
Users can enter numbers between 0 and 50. Numbers outside of that range, except -999, are invalid and the user must re-enter a valid number.
When a user enters the number, it is added to the sum, and the number of users using the program is incremented.
When the value -999. When -999 is entered, the total number of students, total textbooks, and the average number of textbooks are printed.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

int main () {

    const int minBooks = 0, maxBooks = 50;
    int books;
    int sum=0;
    int student = 1;

do {
    cout << "Books: " << endl;
    cin >> books;
    
    student++;
    sum += books;
   
   if (books == -999) {
    cout << "Books: " << sum << "\n" << "Students: " << student << "\n" << "Average" << sum/student<< endl;
    break;
    } 
    
    while (books < minBooks || books > maxBooks)
    {
        cout << "You should at least have " << minBooks << " but no more than " << maxBooks << endl;
        cout << "How many books did you purchased?"<< endl;
        cin >> books;
    } 

} while (books!= -999);

}
```

My problem is that I cant make a program exit after user input is -999.
I tried to change place, use in the loop, out of the loop
If -999 works, then it doesn't validate the input

---

changed while for "if" and now it works
however, it doesn't sum up books and takes only last input which is -999

---

after changing books for sum in two place, now my average is not correct due wrong amount of student; I tried to do decremation but then my average becomes negative

Comment: Change your `while ( books == -999 )` to an `if`

Comment: `books` should probably be an `int`, not a `double`.

Comment: double for books was chosen because I need a division for average later

Comment: That could cause you problems with the comparison because floating point numbers are not exact. Use an int for the book count and a double for the average.

Comment: If the intent is for `student` and `sum` to keep incrementing in each iteration of the loop you need to move the declarations outside the loop. You'll want to take another look at the logic for validating the input as well so `sum` and `student` aren't updated for invalid input.

Comment: Well, you have `if (books == -999) cout << books;` Of course this prints `-999` - you are only printing `books` when it's equal to that value. Now, your program is computing `sum`, but doesn't use that variable in any way - shouldn't it be printing `sum` in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

FIGURED IT OUT, THANKS EVERYONE FOR HELP!
Here are some changes that helped:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

const int minBooks = 0, maxBooks = 50;
int books;
int sum=0;
int student = 0;

do {
cout << "Books: " << endl;
cin >> books;
student++;
sum += books;

if (books == -999) {
student = student - 1;
sum += 999;
cout << "Here is your summary: " << endl;
cout << "Books: " << sum << "\n" << "Students: " << student << "\n" << 
"Average: " << sum/student<< endl;
break;
} 

while (books < minBooks || books > maxBooks)
{
    cout << "You should at least have " << minBooks << " but no more than " << maxBooks << endl;
    cout << "How many books did you purchased?"<< endl;
    cin >> books; 
} 

} while (books!= -999);

}
```